# What is the irreducible set of fundamental principles of Special Relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames

This is something that I have been pondering for some time.
The fundamental principles of special relativity are usually presented as forming a twofold:

1. There is no absolute reference frame of inertia, i.e. the laws of physics do not depend on the frame of reference.
2. The speed of light is a constant in every reference frame.

To me, it always felt like the second one might actually be regarded as a consequence of the first one. That is, the propagation of light being an electromagnetic phenomenon, its physical description ought not to depend on the reference frame. Thus, the speed of light should be a constant.

Yet, once I get it written down, this does not seem right either. 
As, what we call the speed of light, is really the speed of *any massless particle*, its invariability should not really depend on its electromagnetic nature.

Is there not a way to derive the fact that all massless particles travel at the speed of light in every reference frames from principle 1 only?

Any thought?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79963/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Classical Newtonian mechanics is consistent with 1 but not 2. consequently you need *something* extra to differentiate the two cases. You can view the second postulate as saying "the speed of light takes this value, and in particular is not infinite"

Comment: "what we call the speed of light, is really the speed of any massless particle" - why do you state this ? Personally, I totally disagree with "The speed of light is a constant in every reference frame.", because 'c' is actually dictated by the general cosmic field (overlapping of all fields in the universe) and if you isolate the light from that, it will move faster. This has been practically proven in at least 3 independent tunneling experiments.

Comment: @Overmind Until you share your reference, I think you might only be expressing personal beliefs here. Would you care to elaborate in a dedicated space in order not to clutter this thread of comments ? Thx.

Comment: @BySymmetry "Classical Newtonian mechanics is consistent with 1 but not 2" Does it though ? Because, the laws of motion of a particle in an electromagnetic field, for instance, are not invariant under galilean transformations but rather under Lorentz transformations.

Comment: @jrekier Yes, but in that case you have replaced your axiom about the speed of light with one stating that classical electromagnetism exists and includes a particular invariant speed. The point is that I can write down some theory which does have Galilean invariance, so at some point in your reasoning you need to include a postulate do differentiate between that theory and the universe we live in.

Comment: A stone being thrown is a physical phenomenon too, but its speed is not the same in every inertial reference frame...

Comment: Note that even though the character of physical law is the same everywhere, the measured speed of many wave phenomena (speed of sound, speed of surface waves on water, etc.) depend on the frame of reference because those speeds are relative a medium. The second postulate can be re-written in terms of the lack of a medium for light if you prefer, but the wording tends to be awkward.

Comment: "Because, the laws of motion of a particle in an electromagnetic field, for instance, are not invariant under galilean transformations but rather under Lorentz transformations." - That's merely the boundary at which classical mechanics breaks, it has nothing to do with the formulation of the theory. CM is a fully relative theory (and it's not clear to me why you think the inclusion of even em fields would break that).

Comment: @jrekier, yes, please open a chat instance if you want. The problem is way too complex to be explained in just a few comment lines. Some references: Steinberg, A.M., Kwiat, P.G. & R.Y. Chiao 1993: "Measurement of the Single-Photon Tunneling Time" in Physical Review Letter 71, S. 708--711  ; Chiao, R.Y. 1993: "Superluminal propagation of wavepackets in transparent media with inverted atomic populations" in Phys. Rev. A 48, B34. ;Enders, A. und G. Nimtz 1993, "Evanescent-mode propagation and quantum tunneling" in Phys. Rev. E 48, S. 632-634.